# How can I remove all fonts except for defaults?

Tags: wine, 22.04, fonts, default, reset

I would like to know if I could do a hard reset on the installed fonts in Ubuntu without having to remember exactly which ones I installed and manually delete them one by one.

I did a lot of messing around with WINE trying to get fonts to display properly on a foobar2000 skin. I tried installing the normal way, manually putting fonts into usr/share and .local/share, converting the .otf to .ttf and installing those, installing Font Manager, etc. Now I found a new skin with support for Linux, and the fonts they supplied are not displaying properly despite me following their directions. I would like to just do a system reset on fonts, if possible.

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04